# Why is there no space between shift key and its adjacent key?

Tags: keyboard

Why is the keyboard in the picture below designed so that there is no space between the left shift key and its adjacent key to the right?

[image: Keyboard with no space between left shift key and its adjacent key to the right]

Comment: Do the keys work independently without issue or do the keys conflict? Have you asked the manufacturer?

Comment: @John The keys work independently. I got this question with the image from a colleague and I don't know the name of the manufacturer. Now this question has been closed because it's regarded as too brief but I don't know what I'm supposed to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is also a variant of the keyboard designed for countries where users are used to have <kbd>Shift</kbd> next to <kbd>Z</kbd>. They get long <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

The keyboard itself (as a replaceable component) is placed under the top surface of the chassis (white in your photo). Almost every key has its own hole in the chassis. Using a single hole for two adjacent keys allows the manufacturer to use the same chassis with layouts that have a single key there.

You haven't revealed what model the keyboard in question is. Let's use Acer Aspire V3 as an example. This is one of the possible layouts (looks German). Check the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: German layout]

<sup>(source: [www.notebookcheck.net](https://www.notebookcheck.net))</sup>

Another layout (looks Russian). See how the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> are different than in the above layout. The holes in the chassis are identical though.

[image: Russian layout]

<sup>(source: [*How to replace keyboard on Acer Aspire V3-731, V3-771 laptop*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HjMOUNd878&t=267))</sup>

Yet another layout (looks Japanese). It's from an *older* Acer Aspire model; the model seem to use the same layout of holes. See what they did to the <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> and even to the <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

[image: Japanese layout]

<sup>(source: [ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2314585))</sup>